# What is wrong with this geometric representation of an indefinite integral?

Tags: integration

Consider the function y=3. The integral of this is y=3x+C. y=3x is the area increase from zero as if one were taking a definite integral from 0 to x. Now, if you change those bounds to -1 to x, you change the area, acting like the +C. Yet, for functions with finite area (e^(-x^2)), this does not work because it limits the value of C. What is wrong with this representation?

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that representation. There's no contradiction in what you've written.

If $F(x)$ is an anti-derivative of $f(x)$, then so is $F(x)+C$.

$$
\int_a^xf(x)\mathrm dx
$$

is an anti-derivative of $f(x)$ for all $a\in\mathbb R$, but not all anti-derivatives of $f(x)$ can necessarily be written in this form.